# What does the app delegate do in a xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Ok, so when I create a new cocoa project, there's always 2 files that's created for me.  That's the `.h` and the `.m` **NAME** `AppDelegate` file.  I've read a lot of books about cocoa and the documentary from apple that told me to create new files instead of using it.  What's the point of those 2 files anyways?  And is it safe to delete them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not delete the App Delegate! This deals with the main "delegate" notifications for the application like:

- When the application finished loading an is ready for you to add your first controller:

  `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;`
- When the application terminates:

  `-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;`

Check out [this post](http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/application-delegate-for-the-first-iphone-application-explained.aspx) for more information on the app delegate.

The application delegate is one of the most important files in your project!

Comment: Basically the application delegate has a reference to the "window" and then in the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" this is where you know the application has completed launching and you can add your first view controller (or any other type of controller). Also if you are using Core Data in your project the application delegate set up all your references to persistant store co-ordinator, managed object context and managed object model.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to add any code into the appdelegate later?  And can I delete the object that's already originally created in the MainMenu.xib?

Comment: Keep the mainwindow.xib, this has the "window" that is @synthesize'ed in the app delegate and is what you are adding your subviews too. The only code you will need to add to your app delegate is alloc/init'ing the root view controller and adding it to the window, also you may need to add code for responding to uilocalnotifcations, push notifications and performing actions when application terminates (like saving plists). Basically the application delegate deals with the whole lifecycle of the application.

Comment: http://goo.gl/CFiOQ - Apple's Documentation on the application lifecycle / application delegate.

Answer (score 0):

`ProjectNameAppDelegate.h` and `ProjectNameAppDelegate.m` files are created automatically during project creation. These are the first files to be executed. Consider them like a bootstrap for your application.